# How do I conditionally format a cell that contains a dropdown list

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice-calc

Hi Guys I want to know how to conditionally format a cell that contains a drop down list of 3 values. I want each value to represent a different coloured background when selected in the drop down list.

I want the drop down in a cell on Libreoffice Calc to look as follows :
pass (green),
fail (red) 
Identified (orange)

I'm using Libreoffice Calc v.3.5 and I don't get the "text that contains" option in the conditional format dialogue box.

Please help!
Thanks!

New to Libre

Comment: Are you able to format the text based on a formula? Can you add a screenshot showing the Conditional Formatting options that are available to you?

Answer (score 2):

LibreOffice 4.2.6.3 from http://www.libreoffice.org/ - from what I remember this should have entered my machine (w ubuntu 14.04)
through the normal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Type in

```
--Listitems--
pass
fail
identified
```

anywhere on the same sheet.

Press F11 (=> `Menu: Format > Styles and Formatting`)
Create three styles to correspond to red, green and orange background.
Click the "Default" style, then Exit

Place the cursor on a cell where you wish to have the drop-down list

Select `Menu: Data > Validity` click on `/Criteria\` and select `Cell range` at Allow and fill in the cell range (address) of --Listitems-- above.

Select `Menu: Format > Conditional formatting > Condition` and
setup the condition to apply the green, orange and red styles to the cell depending on its content.
The condition has to have three parts "Condition 1" to "...3".
New parts is created by a click on `Add` - Setup for each part similar to the first:
`Cell value is` - `Contains` "pass" -> Apply style `BG-green`
Then check that "Range" contains what you expect, and click OK as you have it correctly.